# Formula needed for report of percent of grand total

Tags: reporting, formula

I have a report with that has a grand total of number of people. The report is grouped by a status. How can I create a formula that gives me the percent of people in each grouping divided by the grand total?

In this example I would need 357/5,754, the field name is People__c and the grouping is status
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the PARENTGROUPVAL in a report custom formula to calculate the percentages for each grouping.

You'd need `People__c:SUM / PARENTGROUPVAL(People__c:SUM, GRAND_SUMMARY)`

Comment: link to 'guide' broken